# Can not resolve this nullPointerException, application keeps stopping

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, nullpointerexception

I am currently working on an application, in the initial stages, I have an error I do not know how to resolve! What I want this application to do is basically retrieve the root node from an xml file which I have created in the assets folder (/app/src/main/assets/tvshows.xml) and display it on the screen using TextView! I am getting a null pointer exception, and the application keeps "Unfortunately, stopping". I would really appreciate it if you could clarify this for me.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView printText;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                Document xmlDoc = getDocument("/app/src/main/res/TvShows/tvshows.xml");
                TextView printText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.printText);
                printText.setText(xmlDoc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());


            }

            private Document getDocument(String domDoc) {
                try {
                    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    factory.setIgnoringComments(true);
                    factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
                    factory.setValidating(true);

                    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                    AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
                InputStream is = assetManager.open("tvshows.xml");

                InputSource inStream = new InputSource(is);
                return builder.parse(inStream);
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    TextView printText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.printText);
                    printText.setText(e.getMessage());
                    return null;
                }
            }



    }
```

error messages:

```
  02-06 15:59:08.271    1973-1973/com.example.ashwinpraveen1.domdoc E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ashwinpraveen1.domdoc/com.example.ashwinpraveen1.domdoc.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2223)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2273)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5145)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.ashwinpraveen1.domdoc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2273)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5145)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the error message.

Comment: @user3249477 Yes, I'm sorry.
 These are the error messages:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
"/app/src/main/res/TvShows/tvshows.xml"
```

`res` is not right place to add files like js,css,html,json or xml.

Put all files in `assets` from which you want to get data in application:

```
AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
InputStream is = assetManager.open("tvshows.xml");
....
InputSource inStream = new InputSource(is);
return builder.parse(inStream);
```

Comment: I have made edits as you've suggested and posted the code above, I am still not able to run it. any suggestions?

Comment: @AshwinPraveen: what is line number 28 in MainActivity.java ?

Comment: line 28 is printText.setText(xmlDoc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

Comment: that error is showing up because we are trying to do an operation on a null object as it is evident that it goes to the catch block.

Comment: @AshwinPraveen: probably `mlDoc.getDocumentElement()` return null so check your parsing logic

Comment: finally got the program working, the problem was factory.setValidating(true)! The program started working when I commented that line.:) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting null pointer exception as getDocument() is returning null. Please check the parsing logic as it is going in catch and returning null.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the path to file like you mentioned in the code.

```
 Document xmlDoc = getDocument("/app/src/main/res/TvShows/tvshows.xml");
 //This is wrong way.
```

Instead put the file in asset folder of the app & then copy the files to local storage in device and then take that path and try to read,

Also don't forgot to check read & write permission in the manifest.

Comment: Could you please possibly post the code? I'm new to this!